# Can Parquet be used to store images? Are there any benefits?

Tags: image, parquet

I understand how parquet works for tabular data and json data.

I'm struggling to understand if/how parquet manages binary images like png files?

Are there any benefits?

Open to moving this question elsewhere, I just couldn't see another community from stack that made sense

Comment: You can always ask on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ what the best site for your question is. I think this probably belongs on https://superuser.com/ ? Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Parquet can store arbitrary byte strings so it can support storing images but it there are no particular benefits for doing so and most bindings aren't necessarily geared to handle very large row sizes, so an image per row could run into some unexpected performance or scalability issues.